# Skaffold can't find image

Tags: docker, skaffold

My Docker file

```
FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS build
RUN apk add gcc musl-dev git
WORKDIR /src
# TODO: How do we ensure up to date? Define as ARG... See im-manager
RUN go install github.com/cespare/reflex@v0.3.1
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download -x
COPY . .
RUN go build -o /app/go-api-gateway -ldflags "-s -w" ./cmd/serve

FROM alpine:3.14
RUN apk --no-cache -U upgrade
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/go-api-gateway .
USER guest
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/go-api-gateway"]
```

My Skaffold file

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta25
kind: Config
build:
  local:
    push: true
  artifacts:
    - image: dhis2/go-api-gateway

deploy:
  statusCheckDeadlineSeconds: 120
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: go-api-gateway-{{ .ENVIRONMENT }}
        namespace: instance-manager-{{ .ENVIRONMENT }}
        createNamespace: true
        chartPath: helm/chart
        artifactOverrides:
          image: dhis2/go-api-gateway
        imageStrategy:
          helm: { }
        useHelmSecrets: true
        valuesFiles:
          - helm/data/values/{{ .ENVIRONMENT }}/values.yaml
```

The error...

```
$ skaffold dev
Listing files to watch...
 - dhis2/go-api-gateway
Generating tags...
 - dhis2/go-api-gateway -> dhis2/go-api-gateway:v0.6.0-dirty
Checking cache...
 - dhis2/go-api-gateway: Not found. Building
Starting build...
Building [dhis2/go-api-gateway]...
Target platforms: [linux/amd64]
WARNING: No output specified for docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
[+] Building 4.0s (19/19) FINISHED                                                                                   
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 556B                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.14                                                  3.7s
 => [auth] library/alpine:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.18-alpine                                           3.6s
 => [auth] library/golang:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                   0.0s
 => [build 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.18-alpine@sha256:3afd220509acf9866e91932a3a41bf341b8bada82107e  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/golang:1.18-alpine@sha256:3afd220509acf9866e91932a3a41bf341b8bada82107ef3ecce  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring context: 181.68kB                                                                           0.1s
 => [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.14@sha256:85c63ff404e9b4daf18f264447161b50ffa70047cc4c033814  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/alpine:3.14@sha256:85c63ff404e9b4daf18f264447161b50ffa70047cc4c03381478cf2c6e  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/4] RUN apk --no-cache -U upgrade                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 3/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/8] RUN apk add gcc musl-dev git                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/8] WORKDIR /src                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build 4/8] RUN go install github.com/cespare/reflex@v0.3.1                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [build 5/8] COPY go.mod go.sum ./                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [build 6/8] RUN go mod download -x                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [build 7/8] COPY . .                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [build 8/8] RUN go build -o /app/go-api-gateway -ldflags "-s -w" ./cmd/serve                         0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 4/4] COPY --from=build /app/go-api-gateway .                                                0.0s
The push refers to repository [docker.io/dhis2/go-api-gateway]
build [dhis2/go-api-gateway] failed: could not push image "dhis2/go-api-gateway:v0.6.0-dirty": tag does not exist: dhis2/go-api-gateway:v0.6.0-dirty
make: *** [Makefile:21: cluster-dev] Error 1
```

Anyone who got a clue about why the tag isn't found?

Comment: Because there is exactly no image tag. Before the "docker push" command needs to be run "docker image build". you may check the following link for more detail https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/

Comment: @newuserua_ext That's what skaffold is supposed to do

Comment: Hey, I just encountered the same error! The image is built and just like yours cached, but Skaffold can't push the image, complaining the tag does not exist. Did you happen to find any solutions?

Comment: Also could you please tell us which version of Skaffold are you using by running `skaffold version`? I think there might be a problem with the new versions

Comment: I've been hitting this error at random the last 3-4 days. I tried switching skaffold versions which has changed the outcome. I also tried to change from Fish to Bash which didn't change anything. The really odd thing is that this is only a problem with 2 of 4 almost identical micro services

Comment: That `tag does not exist` indicates that the attempt to push failed as there was no local image found with that tag.  Earlier in the build there is a warning `WARNING: No output specified for docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load`.  Could you please run with `-vdebug` and include the output (redacted of any personal information or credentials in the environment)?

Comment: Eventually I solved this by doing "docker buildx uninstall". That's obviously not ideal but I had to get my workstation back. I couldn't build anything. I did try to use --load and --push before even posting here. It didn't change anything